# How to build walls for a maze / labyrinth / dungeon?

Tags: java, 3d, blender, ogre, jmonkeyengine

The code I use I just took from an example and it does build a wall to my scene:

```
  /** This loop builds a wall out of individual bricks. */
  public void initWall() {
    float startpt = brickLength / 4;
    float height = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Vector3f vt =
         new Vector3f(i * brickLength * 2 + startpt, brickHeight + height, 10);
        makeBrick(vt);
      }
      startpt = -startpt;
      height += 2 * brickHeight;
    }
  }

  /** This method creates one individual physical brick. */
  public void makeBrick(Vector3f loc) {
    /** Create a brick geometry and attach to scene graph. */
    Geometry brick_geo = new Geometry("brick", box);
    brick_geo.setMaterial(wall_mat);
    rootNode.attachChild(brick_geo);
    /** Position the brick geometry  */
    brick_geo.setLocalTranslation(loc);
    /** Make brick physical with a mass > 0.0f. */
    brick_phy = new RigidBodyControl(2f);
    /** Add physical brick to physics space. */
    brick_geo.addControl(brick_phy);
    bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(brick_phy);
  }
```

[image]

Now I wonder if I should use this code to build up an entire labyrinth / dungeon or if this is best modelled outside the program eg. in blender instead like a .scene and then read into the program? The entire program is

```
package adventure;

import java.applet.Applet;
import com.jme3.math.Quaternion;
import com.jme3.math.FastMath;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.jme3.material.RenderState.FaceCullMode;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import com.jme3.renderer.queue.RenderQueue.ShadowMode;
import com.jme3.animation.AnimChannel;
import com.jme3.animation.AnimControl;
import com.jme3.animation.AnimEventListener;
import com.jme3.animation.LoopMode;
import com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication;
import com.jme3.asset.BlenderKey;
import com.jme3.asset.TextureKey;
import com.jme3.asset.plugins.ZipLocator;
import com.jme3.bullet.BulletAppState;
import com.jme3.bullet.PhysicsSpace;
import com.jme3.bullet.collision.PhysicsCollisionEvent;
import com.jme3.bullet.collision.PhysicsCollisionListener;
import com.jme3.bullet.collision.shapes.CapsuleCollisionShape;
import com.jme3.bullet.collision.shapes.CollisionShape;
import com.jme3.bullet.collision.shapes.SphereCollisionShape;
import com.jme3.bullet.control.CharacterControl;
import com.jme3.bullet.control.RigidBodyControl;
import com.jme3.bullet.util.CollisionShapeFactory;
import com.jme3.effect.ParticleEmitter;
import com.jme3.effect.ParticleMesh.Type;
import com.jme3.effect.shapes.EmitterSphereShape;
import com.jme3.input.ChaseCamera;
import com.jme3.input.KeyInput;
import com.jme3.input.controls.ActionListener;
import com.jme3.input.controls.KeyTrigger;
import com.jme3.light.DirectionalLight;
import com.jme3.material.Material;
import com.jme3.math.ColorRGBA;
import com.jme3.math.Vector2f;
import com.jme3.math.Vector3f;
import com.jme3.post.FilterPostProcessor;
import com.jme3.post.filters.BloomFilter;
import com.jme3.renderer.Camera;
import com.jme3.renderer.queue.RenderQueue.ShadowMode;
import com.jme3.scene.Geometry;
import com.jme3.scene.Node;
import com.jme3.scene.Spatial;
import com.jme3.scene.shape.Box;
import com.jme3.scene.shape.Sphere;
import com.jme3.scene.shape.Sphere.TextureMode;
import com.jme3.system.AppSettings;
import com.jme3.system.JmeCanvasContext;
import com.jme3.terrain.geomipmap.TerrainLodControl;
import com.jme3.terrain.geomipmap.TerrainQuad;
import com.jme3.terrain.heightmap.AbstractHeightMap;
import com.jme3.terrain.heightmap.ImageBasedHeightMap;
import com.jme3.texture.Texture;
import com.jme3.texture.Texture.WrapMode;
import com.jme3.util.SkyFactory;

public class MountainWorld extends SimpleApplication implements ActionListener,
        PhysicsCollisionListener, AnimEventListener, Playable {






      /** Prepare Materials */
      Material wall_mat;
      Material stone_mat;
      Material floor_mat;

      /** Prepare geometries and physical nodes for bricks and cannon balls. */
      private RigidBodyControl    brick_phy;
      private static final Box    box;
      private RigidBodyControl    ball_phy;
      private static final Sphere sphere;
      private RigidBodyControl    floor_phy;
      private static final Box    floor;

      /** dimensions used for bricks and wall */
      private static final float brickLength = 0.48f;
      private static final float brickWidth  = 0.24f;
      private static final float brickHeight = 0.12f;

      static {
        /** Initialize the cannon ball geometry */
        sphere = new Sphere(32, 32, 0.4f, true, false);
        sphere.setTextureMode(TextureMode.Projected);
        /** Initialize the brick geometry */
        box = new Box(Vector3f.ZERO, brickLength, brickHeight, brickWidth);
        box.scaleTextureCoordinates(new Vector2f(1f, .5f));
        /** Initialize the floor geometry */
        floor = new Box(Vector3f.ZERO, 100f, 0.1f, 50f);
        floor.scaleTextureCoordinates(new Vector2f(3, 6));
      }







    private static World world;
    private static Person person;
    private static Player dplayer;
    private static TextArea textarea;
    private BulletAppState bulletAppState;
    private AnimChannel channel;
    private AnimControl control;
    // character
    CharacterControl character;
    Node model;
    // temp vectors
    Vector3f walkDirection = new Vector3f();
    // terrain
    TerrainQuad terrain;
    RigidBodyControl terrainPhysicsNode;
    // Materials
    Material matRock;
    Material matBullet;
    // animation
    AnimChannel animationChannel;
    AnimChannel shootingChannel;
    AnimControl animationControl;
    float airTime = 0;
    // camera
    boolean left = false, right = false, up = false, down = false;
    ChaseCamera chaseCam;
    // bullet
    Sphere bullet;
    SphereCollisionShape bulletCollisionShape;
    // explosion
    ParticleEmitter effect;
    // brick wall
    Box brick;
    float bLength = 0.8f;
    float bWidth = 0.4f;
    float bHeight = 0.4f;
    FilterPostProcessor fpp;
    private Spatial sceneModel;

    private RigidBodyControl landscape;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AppSettings settings = new AppSettings(true);
                settings.setWidth(850);
                settings.setHeight(440);

                MountainWorld canvasApplication = new MountainWorld();
                canvasApplication.setSettings(settings);
                canvasApplication.createCanvas(); // create canvas!
                JmeCanvasContext ctx = (JmeCanvasContext) canvasApplication
                        .getContext();
                ctx.setSystemListener(canvasApplication);
                Dimension dim = new Dimension(640, 480);
                ctx.getCanvas().setPreferredSize(dim);

                JFrame window = new JFrame("Dungeon World");
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // a panel
                world = new DungeonWorld(canvasApplication);
                person = new Person(world, "You", null);
                dplayer = new Player(world, person);
                Commands commands = new Commands(person);
                textarea = new TextArea("", 10, 60,
                        TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
                textarea.append("You are in a dungeon. The horrible shrieks of the undead chill your bones.\n");
                textarea.setEditable(false);
                panel.add("West", ctx.getCanvas());
                panel.add("East", commands);
                panel.add("South", textarea);
                window.add(panel);
                window.pack();
                window.setVisible(true);
                canvasApplication.startCanvas();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        bulletAppState = new BulletAppState();
        bulletAppState.setThreadingType(BulletAppState.ThreadingType.PARALLEL);
        stateManager.attach(bulletAppState);
        setupKeys();
        //prepareBullet();
        //prepareEffect();
        createLight();
        //createSky();
        initMaterials();
        initFloor();
        initWall();
        //createTerrain();
        //createWall();
        createCharacters();
        setupChaseCamera();
        setupAnimationController();
        setupFilter();
    }

      /** This loop builds a wall out of individual bricks. */
      public void initWall() {
        float startpt = brickLength / 4;
        float height = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            Vector3f vt =
             new Vector3f(i * brickLength * 2 + startpt, brickHeight + height, 10);
            makeBrick(vt);
          }
          startpt = -startpt;
          height += 2 * brickHeight;
        }
      }

      /** This method creates one individual physical brick. */
      public void makeBrick(Vector3f loc) {
        /** Create a brick geometry and attach to scene graph. */
        Geometry brick_geo = new Geometry("brick", box);
        brick_geo.setMaterial(wall_mat);
        rootNode.attachChild(brick_geo);
        /** Position the brick geometry  */
        brick_geo.setLocalTranslation(loc);
        /** Make brick physical with a mass > 0.0f. */
        brick_phy = new RigidBodyControl(2f);
        /** Add physical brick to physics space. */
        brick_geo.addControl(brick_phy);
        bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(brick_phy);
      }

     /** Make a solid floor and add it to the scene. */
      public void initFloor() {
        Geometry floor_geo = new Geometry("Floor", floor);
        floor_geo.setMaterial(floor_mat);
        floor_geo.setLocalTranslation(0, -0.1f, 0);
        this.rootNode.attachChild(floor_geo);
        /* Make the floor physical with mass 0.0f! */
        floor_phy = new RigidBodyControl(0.0f);
        floor_geo.addControl(floor_phy);
        bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(floor_phy);
      }

      /** Initialize the materials used in this scene. */
      public void initMaterials() {
        wall_mat = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        TextureKey key = new TextureKey("Textures/Terrain/BrickWall/BrickWall.jpg");
        key.setGenerateMips(true);
        Texture tex = assetManager.loadTexture(key);
        wall_mat.setTexture("ColorMap", tex);

        stone_mat = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        TextureKey key2 = new TextureKey("Textures/Terrain/Rock/Rock.PNG");
        key2.setGenerateMips(true);
        Texture tex2 = assetManager.loadTexture(key2);
        stone_mat.setTexture("ColorMap", tex2);

        floor_mat = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        TextureKey key3 = new TextureKey("Textures/Terrain/Pond/Pond.jpg");
        key3.setGenerateMips(true);
        Texture tex3 = assetManager.loadTexture(key3);
        tex3.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        floor_mat.setTexture("ColorMap", tex3);
      }


    private void setupFilter() {
        FilterPostProcessor fpp = new FilterPostProcessor(assetManager);
        BloomFilter bloom = new BloomFilter(BloomFilter.GlowMode.Objects);
        fpp.addFilter(bloom);
        viewPort.addProcessor(fpp);
    }

    private PhysicsSpace getPhysicsSpace() {
        return bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace();
    }

    private void setupKeys() {
        inputManager.addMapping("wireframe", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_T));
        inputManager.addListener(this, "wireframe");
        inputManager.addMapping("CharLeft", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_A));
        inputManager.addMapping("CharRight", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_D));
        inputManager.addMapping("CharUp", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_W));
        inputManager.addMapping("CharDown", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_S));
        inputManager.addMapping("CharSpace",
                new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_RETURN));
        inputManager
                .addMapping("CharShoot", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_SPACE));
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharLeft");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharRight");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharUp");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharDown");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharSpace");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharShoot");
    }

    private void createWall() {
        float xOff = -144;
        float zOff = -40;
        float startpt = bLength / 4 - xOff;
        float height = 6.1f;
        brick = new Box(Vector3f.ZERO, bLength, bHeight, bWidth);
        brick.scaleTextureCoordinates(new Vector2f(1f, .5f));
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                Vector3f vt = new Vector3f(i * bLength * 2 + startpt, bHeight
                        + height, zOff);
                addBrick(vt);
            }
            startpt = -startpt;
            height += 1.01f * bHeight;
        }
    }

    private void addBrick(Vector3f ori) {
        Geometry reBoxg = new Geometry("brick", brick);
        reBoxg.setMaterial(matBullet);
        reBoxg.setLocalTranslation(ori);
        reBoxg.addControl(new RigidBodyControl(1.5f));
        reBoxg.setShadowMode(ShadowMode.CastAndReceive);
        this.rootNode.attachChild(reBoxg);
        this.getPhysicsSpace().add(reBoxg);
    }

    private void prepareBullet() {
        bullet = new Sphere(32, 32, 0.4f, true, false);
        bullet.setTextureMode(TextureMode.Projected);
        bulletCollisionShape = new SphereCollisionShape(0.4f);
        matBullet = new Material(getAssetManager(),
                "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        matBullet.setColor("Color", ColorRGBA.Green);
        // matBullet.setColor("m_GlowColor", ColorRGBA.Green);
        getPhysicsSpace().addCollisionListener(this);
    }

    private void prepareEffect() {
        int COUNT_FACTOR = 1;
        float COUNT_FACTOR_F = 1f;
        effect = new ParticleEmitter("Flame", Type.Triangle, 32 * COUNT_FACTOR);
        effect.setSelectRandomImage(true);
        effect.setStartColor(new ColorRGBA(1f, 0.4f, 0.05f,
                (float) (1f / COUNT_FACTOR_F)));
        effect.setEndColor(new ColorRGBA(.4f, .22f, .12f, 0f));
        effect.setStartSize(1.3f);
        effect.setEndSize(2f);
        effect.setShape(new EmitterSphereShape(Vector3f.ZERO, 1f));
        effect.setParticlesPerSec(0);
        effect.setGravity(0, -5, 0);
        effect.setLowLife(.4f);
        effect.setHighLife(.5f);
        effect.setInitialVelocity(new Vector3f(0, 7, 0));
        effect.setVelocityVariation(1f);
        effect.setImagesX(2);
        effect.setImagesY(2);
        Material mat = new Material(assetManager,
                "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Particle.j3md");
        mat.setTexture("Texture",
                assetManager.loadTexture("Effects/Explosion/flame.png"));
        effect.setMaterial(mat);
        // effect.setLocalScale(100);
        rootNode.attachChild(effect);
    }

    private void createLight() {
        Vector3f direction = new Vector3f(-0.1f, -0.7f, -1).normalizeLocal();
        DirectionalLight dl = new DirectionalLight();
        dl.setDirection(direction);
        dl.setColor(new ColorRGBA(1f, 1f, 1f, 1.0f));
        rootNode.addLight(dl);
    }

    private void createSky() {
        rootNode.attachChild(SkyFactory.createSky(assetManager,
                "Textures/Sky/Bright/BrightSky.dds", false));
    }

    private void createTerrain2() {
        matRock = new Material(assetManager,
                "Common/MatDefs/Terrain/TerrainLighting.j3md");
        matRock.setBoolean("useTriPlanarMapping", false);
        matRock.setBoolean("WardIso", true);
        matRock.setTexture("AlphaMap",
                assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/alphamap.png"));
        Texture heightMapImage = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/mountains512.png");
        Texture grass = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/grass.jpg");
        grass.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        matRock.setTexture("DiffuseMap", grass);
        matRock.setFloat("DiffuseMap_0_scale", 64);
        Texture dirt = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/dirt.jpg");
        dirt.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        matRock.setTexture("DiffuseMap_1", dirt);
        matRock.setFloat("DiffuseMap_1_scale", 16);
        Texture rock = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/road.jpg");
        rock.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        matRock.setTexture("DiffuseMap_2", rock);
        matRock.setFloat("DiffuseMap_2_scale", 128);
        Texture normalMap0 = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/grass_normal.jpg");
        normalMap0.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        Texture normalMap1 = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/dirt_normal.png");
        normalMap1.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        Texture normalMap2 = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/road_normal.png");
        normalMap2.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        matRock.setTexture("NormalMap", normalMap0);
        matRock.setTexture("NormalMap_1", normalMap2);
        matRock.setTexture("NormalMap_2", normalMap2);

        AbstractHeightMap heightmap = null;
        try {
            heightmap = new ImageBasedHeightMap(heightMapImage.getImage(),
                    0.25f);
            heightmap.load();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        terrain = new TerrainQuad("terrain", 65, 513, heightmap.getHeightMap());
        List<Camera> cameras = new ArrayList<Camera>();
        cameras.add(getCamera());
        TerrainLodControl control = new TerrainLodControl(terrain, cameras);
        terrain.addControl(control);
        terrain.setMaterial(matRock);
        terrain.setLocalScale(new Vector3f(2, 2, 2));

        terrainPhysicsNode = new RigidBodyControl(
                CollisionShapeFactory.createMeshShape(terrain), 0);
        terrain.addControl(terrainPhysicsNode);
        rootNode.attachChild(terrain);
        getPhysicsSpace().add(terrainPhysicsNode);
    }

    private void createTerrain() {


         assetManager.registerLocator("town.zip", ZipLocator.class);
         sceneModel = assetManager.loadModel("main.scene");
        //sceneModel = assetManager.loadModel("Scenes/ManyLights/Main.scene");
        sceneModel.setLocalScale(2f);
        //initFloor();
        // We set up collision detection for the scene by creating a
        // compound collision shape and a static RigidBodyControl with mass
        // zero.
        CollisionShape sceneShape = CollisionShapeFactory
                .createMeshShape((Node) sceneModel);
        landscape = new RigidBodyControl(sceneShape, 0);
        sceneModel.addControl(landscape);
        List<Camera> cameras = new ArrayList<Camera>();
        cameras.add(getCamera());
        rootNode.attachChild(sceneModel);
    }

    private void createCharacters() {
        CapsuleCollisionShape capsule = new CapsuleCollisionShape(0.0f, 0.0f);
        character = new CharacterControl(capsule, 0.01f);
        model = (Node) assetManager.loadModel("Models/Ninja/Ninja.mesh.xml");
        float scale = 0.25f;
        model.scale(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
        model.addControl(character);
        character.setPhysicsLocation(new Vector3f(0, -0.05f, 0));
        model.setShadowMode(ShadowMode.CastAndReceive);
        character.setViewDirection(new Vector3f(1, 0, 0));
        rootNode.attachChild(model);
        getPhysicsSpace().add(character);

        BlenderKey blenderKey = new BlenderKey("Models/Oto/Oto.mesh.xml");

        Spatial man = (Spatial) assetManager.loadModel(blenderKey);
        man.setLocalTranslation(new Vector3f(-10, 4.5f, -10));

         man.setShadowMode(ShadowMode.CastAndReceive);
        rootNode.attachChild(man);

    }

    private void setupChaseCamera() {
        flyCam.setEnabled(false);
        chaseCam = new ChaseCamera(cam, model, inputManager);
    }

    private void setupAnimationController() {
        animationControl = model.getControl(AnimControl.class);
        animationControl.addListener(this);
        animationChannel = animationControl.createChannel();
        // shootingChannel = animationControl.createChannel();
        // shootingChannel.addBone(animationControl.getSkeleton().getBone(
        // "uparm.right"));
        // shootingChannel.addBone(animationControl.getSkeleton().getBone(
        // "arm.right"));
        // shootingChannel.addBone(animationControl.getSkeleton().getBone(
        // "hand.right"));
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
        Vector3f camDir = cam.getDirection().clone().multLocal(0.1f);
        Vector3f camLeft = cam.getLeft().clone().multLocal(0.1f);
        camDir.y = 0;
        camLeft.y = 0;
        walkDirection.set(0, 0, 0);
        if (left) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camLeft);
        }
        if (right) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camLeft.negate());
        }
        if (up) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camDir);
        }
        if (down) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camDir.negate());
        }
        if (!character.onGround()) {
            airTime = airTime + tpf;
        } else {
            airTime = 0;
        }
        if (walkDirection.length() == 0) {
            if (!"Idle1".equals(animationChannel.getAnimationName())) {
                animationChannel.setAnim("Idle1", 1f);
            }
        } else {
            character.setViewDirection(walkDirection);
            if (airTime > .3f) {
                if (!"stand".equals(animationChannel.getAnimationName())) {
                    animationChannel.setAnim("stand");
                }
            } else if (!"Walk".equals(animationChannel.getAnimationName())) {
                animationChannel.setAnim("Walk", 0.7f);
            }
        }
        character.setWalkDirection(walkDirection);
    }

    public void onAction(String binding, boolean value, float tpf) {
        if (binding.equals("CharLeft")) {
            if (value) {
                left = true;
            } else {
                left = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("CharRight")) {
            if (value) {
                right = true;
            } else {
                right = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("CharUp")) {
            if (value) {
                up = true;
            } else {
                up = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("CharDown")) {
            if (value) {
                down = true;
            } else {
                down = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("CharSpace")) {
            character.jump();
        } else if (binding.equals("CharShoot") && !value) {
            bulletControl();
        }
    }

    private void bulletControl() {
        shootingChannel.setAnim("Dodge", 0.1f);
        shootingChannel.setLoopMode(LoopMode.DontLoop);
        Geometry bulletg = new Geometry("bullet", bullet);
        bulletg.setMaterial(matBullet);
        bulletg.setShadowMode(ShadowMode.CastAndReceive);
        bulletg.setLocalTranslation(character.getPhysicsLocation().add(
                cam.getDirection().mult(5)));
        RigidBodyControl bulletControl = new BombControl(bulletCollisionShape,
                1);
        bulletControl.setCcdMotionThreshold(0.1f);
        bulletControl.setLinearVelocity(cam.getDirection().mult(80));
        bulletg.addControl(bulletControl);
        rootNode.attachChild(bulletg);
        getPhysicsSpace().add(bulletControl);
    }

    public void collision(PhysicsCollisionEvent event) {
        if (event.getObjectA() instanceof BombControl) {
            final Spatial node = event.getNodeA();
            effect.killAllParticles();
            effect.setLocalTranslation(node.getLocalTranslation());
            effect.emitAllParticles();
        } else if (event.getObjectB() instanceof BombControl) {
            final Spatial node = event.getNodeB();
            effect.killAllParticles();
            effect.setLocalTranslation(node.getLocalTranslation());
            effect.emitAllParticles();
        }
    }

    public void onAnimCycleDone(AnimControl control, AnimChannel channel,
            String animName) {
        if (channel == shootingChannel) {
            channel.setAnim("stand");
        }
    }

    public void onAnimChange(AnimControl control, AnimChannel channel,
            String animName) {
    }

    // Load an image from the net, making sure it has already been
    // loaded when the method returns
    public Image loadPicture(String imageName) {
        return null;
    }

    // Load and play a sound from /usr/local/hacks/sounds/

    public void playSound(String name) {
        URL u = null;

        try {
            u = new URL("file:" + "/usr/local/hacks/sounds/" + name + ".au");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        }

        AudioClip a = Applet.newAudioClip(u);
        a.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your question "should I generate the maze in Java at runtime oder only load a `.scene` file?", or is your question "What are good [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm) for [maze generation](http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm#create)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you have about 100+ bricks - just imagine how many of them you'll need for full dungeon and how it will kill your physics performance :). It's almost impossible do create playable game with this approach.

You should create some static mesh and divide it into corridors, rooms, etc. so you could draw only visible part of your level. If you really want to create destructible environment you should still use static mesh and dynamically replace parts of it with the bricks when the wall should be destroyed.